# Grunt Configuration Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have a grunt task to concatenate all js files in to one.The configurations is like below.

```
concat:{
      options: {
        separator: ';'
      },
      dist:{
        src:['src/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      }
    }
```

The problem is that it is concatenating the test files also which is not required. The test files are having names like "*Spec.js". For example I am having a js file like test.js, then its test file will be like testSpec.js. How Can i exclude them while concatenating the js files?

Comment: What if you do `src:["src/**/*.js", "!src/**/*Spec.js"]`?

Comment: Thank you. 
Can you post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Since all your test files have prefix "test", you can ignore files using ! (negate):

```
// All files except for bar.js, in alpha order:
{src: ['foo/*.js', '!foo/bar.js'], dest: ...}
```

So your code should be like:

```
   concat:{
      options: {
        separator: ';'
      },
      dist:{
        src:['src/**/*.js', '!src/**/test*.js'],
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      }
    }
```

This will ignore all the files which has a prefix "test".